# Differential Equation problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find $y$, when $xy'-x=1$ and $y(1)=2$.

I get that $y=x+\ln{ x}+C$

But then $y(1)=2$ isn't true. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You are supposed to sub in $x=1$ and $y=2$ to find the constant $C$.

Comment: we get $1+C=2$ can you solve this

Comment: Of course, I knew that..... Just misunderstood my teacher then, but thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, $\ \ y(x) = x + \ln(x) + C\ \ $ is called the 'general' solution, because no matter what value of $C$ is used, this function satisfies your differential equation.

You have a more specific problem however, they want you to solve for a function which satisfies two conditions! The differential equation as well as the condition that $y(1) = 2$. Having this condition allows you to find a $C$ which gives you a 'particular' solution for the problem as a whole.